# How do I create tables in Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Express

Tags: sql-server, database, windows

I have installed Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Express R2 with tools. In windows start menu now I have an option for SQL Server Management Studio. So I click on that and a dialogue window pops up asking me to connect to a server. I don't know what server to enter into here and all I want to do is create a new database so I can store some simple information in tables. I did press cancel on the dialogue box and looked around in the management studio but I couldn't find a "create new table" option or anything particularly like that.

Answer (score 1):

It's looking for <%ComputerName%>\SQLEXPRESS

If you don't know the name of your compter then...

Click Start
Right Click on My Computer
Click Properties
Click ComputerName tab

Answer (score 0):

I haven't played around with the manager studio in a while, but I hope this helps
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186312.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Use `localhost` as your server if you don't need to connect to an external server. Then in `Object Explorer` you'll be able to create new `Databases` and `Tables` within those databases